# How can I move files between mounts using Python?

Tags: python, file, operating-system, move

I've been using `os.rename` to move files in Python. However, it appears that this fails if you try to move files between one mountpoint and another (on Linux).

Is there a Python library or function to move files between mountpoints, similar to `mv` on Linux?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a common caveat with `os.rename`. The higher level `shutil` module and it's `move` method works around this for you by using `os.rename()` or `shutil.copy2()` as appropriate.

One thing to keep in mind is that this loses the atomic guarantee that `os.rename` has if it isn't on the same filesystem.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move

Comment: Also note that Python is paralleling POSIX pretty closely here. The docs for `mv` specify that, because `rename` doesn't work across filesystems, `mv` should use `cp` and `rm` if it fails. Equivalently, `os.rename` doesn't work across filesystems, `shutil.move` uses `copy2` and the appropriate remove function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mv` using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(["mv","src","dest"])
```

Comment: Thanks. That works, but I think the other solution (`shutil.move`) is cleaner.